# Horizontal centering in table - alternative to array package

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am very new to LaTex and I am having some problems with centering values in a table. I have created the table as below.

```
\documentclass[11pt. oneside]{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{geometry}                       % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                          % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
\geometry{landscape}                        % Activate for rotated page geometry
\usepackage{graphicx}               % Use pdf. png. jpg\includegraphics[]{../../../../../../../Desktop/CenterTest.pdf}
\usepackage{array}                              % TeX will automatically convert eps --> pdf in pdflatex        
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false
]{caption}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Overview of measures.}
\label{This is a label}
\begin{tabular}{llllllllllll}
\hline
\thead{Locus} & \thead{Population (\textit{N})} & \thead{Sequence\\length} &     \thead{Number of polymorphic\\sites} & \thead{Number of\\alleles} &     \thead{Allelic\\richness} & \thead{Amino acid\\variants} &     \thead{Nucleotide\\diversity}   & \thead{Haplotype\\diversity (S.D.)} & \thead{Ho}     & \thead{He} & \thead{H.W.E. \textit{P} (S.E.)} \\
\hline \\
Numb1 & S (10)  &       & 3 & 1 & 5.60  & 1 & 12.4  & 0.423     & 0.50  & 0.43  & 0.006 \\
   & F(10)      &       & 2 & 6 & 5.80  & 2 & 13.6  & 0.423     & 0.70  & 0.45      & 0.309 (0.017) \\
   & S(7)       &       & 1 & 2 & 1.00  & 1 & 0     & 0.123     & 0.00  & 0.00      & NA                \\
   & Tot (27)       & 423 bp  & 10  & 8 &       & 2 & 12.4  & 0.321 (0.037) &       &           &                 \\
Numb2 & S (11)  &           & 4 & 5 & 5.12  & 1 & 3.4       & 0.423     & 0.73  & 0.32      & 1.000 (0.000)   \\
   & F (10)         &           & 3 & 1 & 3.12  & 2 & 12.3  & 0.453     & 0.90  & 0.78      & 1.000 (0.000)   \\
   & S (10)         &           & 2 & 1 & 4.32  & 1 & 1     & 0.246     & 0.00      & 0.01      & NA               \\
   & Tot(31)        & 324 bp  & 1   & 4 &       & 2 & 10.9  & 0.625 (0.067) &               &           &                  \\  
\end{tabular}%
%}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table 1]

The table is perfect, except I would like to horizontally center the values in it. In my research I have found, that I am suppose to use `\usepackage{array}`then define a column type with `\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`and create the table with:

```
\begin{tabular}{|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|}
```

With this, I do get centering of the values, but it also changes the table layout/look completely. Is there an alternative way to get the values centered, without changing the layout?

[image: Table2]

Comment: What do you mean with `changes the layout`? The vertical rules? Just omit then. For the columns with decimal numbers you might consider using the `S` column type from `siunitx`, for example

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest that you use a `tabularx` environment nested inside a `sidewaystable` environment. Set the width of the `tabularx` environment, and use a centered version of the `X` column type for columns 9 of the 12 columns; doing so will allow automatic line breaking, if needed. Regarding the remaining three columns: I suggest you the `l` column type for the first column and the `c` column type for the columns headed by "Ho" and "He".

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  % select page-related parameters
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Overview of measures.}
\label{This is a label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{8}{C}ccC@{}}
\toprule
Locus & Population (\textit{N}) & Sequence length & Number of polymorphic sites & Number of alleles & Allelic richness & Amino acid variants & Nucleo\-tide diversity & Haplotype diversity (S.D.) & Ho & He & H.W.E. \textit{P} (S.E.) \\
\midrule
Numb1 & S (10) & & 3 & 1 & 5.60 & 1 & 12.4 & 0.423 & 0.50 & 0.43 & 0.006 \\
      & F(10) & & 2 & 6 & 5.80 & 2 & 13.6 & 0.423 & 0.70 & 0.45 & 0.309 (0.017) \\
      & S(7) & & 1 & 2 & 1.00 & 1 & 0 & 0.123 & 0.00 & 0.00 & NA \\
      & Tot (27) & 423 bp & 10 & 8 & & 2 & 12.4 & 0.321 (0.037) & & & \\
Numb2 & S (11) & & 4 & 5 & 5.12 & 1 & 3.4 & 0.423 & 0.73 & 0.32 & 1.000 (0.000) \\
      & F (10) & & 3 & 1 & 3.12 & 2 & 12.3 & 0.453 & 0.90 & 0.78 & 1.000 (0.000) \\
      & S (10) & & 2 & 1 & 4.32 & 1 & 1 & 0.246 & 0.00 & 0.01 & NA \\
      & Tot(31) & 324 bp & 1 & 4 & & 2 & 10.9 & 0.625 (0.067) & & &\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you don't want to permit line breaks in the cells in the body of your table, it's advisable to use non-breaking spaces (`~`), to switch to a smaller fontsize (e.g., `\footnotesize`), and to reduce the value of intercolumn whitespace by a third (from 6 to 4 points).

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  % select page-related parameters
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\caption{Overview of measures.}
\label{This is a label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{8}{C}ccC@{}}
\toprule
Locus & Population (\textit{N}) & Sequence length & Number of polymorphic sites & Number of alleles & Allelic richness & Amino acid variants & Nucleo\-tide diversity & Haplotype diversity (S.D.) & Ho & He & H.W.E. \textit{P} (S.E.) \\
\midrule
Numb1 & S (10) & & 3 & 1 & 5.60 & 1 & 12.4 & 0.423 & 0.50 & 0.43 & 0.006 \\
      & F(10) & & 2 & 6 & 5.80 & 2 & 13.6 & 0.423 & 0.70 & 0.45 & 0.309~(0.017) \\
      & S(7) & & 1 & 2 & 1.00 & 1 & 0 & 0.123 & 0.00 & 0.00 & NA \\
      & Tot (27) & 423 bp & 10 & 8 & & 2 & 12.4 & 0.321~(0.037) & & & \\ \addlinespace
Numb2 & S (11) & & 4 & 5 & 5.12 & 1 & 3.4 & 0.423 & 0.73 & 0.32 & 1.000~(0.000) \\
      & F (10) & & 3 & 1 & 3.12 & 2 & 12.3 & 0.453 & 0.90 & 0.78 & 1.000~(0.000) \\
      & S (10) & & 2 & 1 & 4.32 & 1 & 1 & 0.246 & 0.00 & 0.01 & NA \\
      & Tot(31) & 324 bp & 1 & 4 & & 2 & 10.9 & 0.625~(0.067) & & &\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at this! The first thing that springs to eye in your screenshot, is that the values in parenthesis get their own row even though they should not. E.g. the value (0.067) in haplotype diversity column should be on the right of the value 0.625, as it is written in the code, and not  have a line break to the next column.

Comment: @Hjalte - I've posted an addendum to address your follow-up query.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on the use of `~`. That's very useful! One problem I have, and also the reason why I am experimenting with the `siunitx`package in parallel with this, is that when you force the parenthesis values to stay on the same row, the entry is not aligned the way I would like it. I would prefer the values to be aligned by decimal-point, and the Ho column to be pushed to the right, to makes space for this.

Comment: @Hjalte - The 2nd table shown in my answer is already severely space-constrained, even though it is typeset in landscape mode. If you additionally want to align numbers on their decimal markers, you'll probably have to switch from `\footnotesize` to `\scriptsize` or even `\tiny` -- more or less guaranteeing that nobody will be able to read the table without the aid of a magnifying glass. :-( By the way, I'm puzzled as to why you don't want to set the numbers in parentheses (standard errors, right?) *below* the corresponding numbers. Doing so would significantly alleviate the space constraints.

Comment: I understand. I didn't really consider this constraint (or I did, but I guess I didn't realize I was getting close to the limit of what is advisable). Thank you for that note. As to why I do not want the variance (standard error and standard deviation) under the corresponding number - I guess it's just a matter of taste - I like the look better when they are adjacent to the corresponding number. I would also say this is custom in scientific publications. But I understand your point, that it would free up some space!

Answer (score 0):

To center elements in a table you just have to replace all your l by c like that:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
1 & 2 \\
\hline
3 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: The caveat of this is long content doesn't wrap any longer with `c`

Comment: You answered my question correctly. However, I realize now that my problem is more complicated than I first thought. What I really want, is the columns to be centered (so the values are centered in relation to the heading, but the values themselves should still be aligned to the left. I assume this is a bit more difficult to do and may require asking a new question?

Comment: @Hjalte: I don't understand how values could be left aligned while being centred w.r.t. to the heading. Would you mean their decimal dots should aligned, per chance?

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution, Bernard. I have now found that the `siuntix` package does more or less what I am after. I have edited my question to include this.

Answer (score 0):

I have now found that the siuntix package does what I am looking for.

```
\documentclass[19pt. oneside]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{landscape}  
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}            
\usepackage{array}                              
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false 
]{caption}



\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false
]{caption}


\newcommand{\boldentry}[2]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{S[table-format=#1,
                   mode=text,
                    text-rm=\fontseries{b}\selectfont
                   ]}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} %Removes page number
\begin{table}[h]
 \begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{} %Adjusts table to the left, so all can be seen
    \caption{This is the caption}
    \begin{tabular}{lSSSSSSSSSSl} \toprule
{Header 1} & {\shortstack{Header (\textit{2})}} & {\shortstack{Header\\number     3}} & {\shortstack{Header\\ number 4}} &{ \shortstack{Header\\ 5}} &     {\shortstack{Header\\number 6}} & {\shortstack{Header\\number 7}} & {Header number (8)}   & {\shortstack{Header\\number (9)}} & {Header number 10} & {Header number 11} & {\shortstack{Header \textit{Number 12}}} \\
\midrule
{TLR1234}       & {Total (10)}  & {100 mm}  & 100   & 2.00  & 300   & 400   & 500       & 600 {(700)}   &               &               &                 \\
& {ST (10)}         &               & 100           & 2.00          & 300           & 400       & 500       & 600   & 700           & 800   & 900 \\
& {FG (10)}         &               & 100       & 20.13         & 300        & 400      & 500       & 600       & 700           & 800   & {900 (1000)} \\
& {SN (10)}             &           & 100           & 20.02        & 300        & 400       & 500       & 600       & 700           & 800       & 900                \\
 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
 \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

With this, I can get the entries of the table aligned by decimal point, while the column itself is aligned to the center of the header. As so:

[image: Aligned]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got what are looking for but I feel like throwing my hat into the ring.

The code below is an example on how one can align one row of a table different than the others:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|r|r|}
\hline
Centered&Centered&Right&Right\\
\hline
Centered&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Left}&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Left}&r\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You simply use the `\multicolumn` command to align the cell in question different. What you exactly do is to tell the cell that it is a multicolumn cell with the size of one cell and the alignment you want.

For more information on the `\multicolumn` command see [this link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Rows_spanning_multiple_columns).